# How to Escape hyphen-minus sign in MongoDB Text Search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to search -2 in my database. But hyphen-minus is a special character for neglation. How can I escape hyphen-minus to find sentences that contains -2 in it.

My query:

```
Message.find({ "$text": { $search: "-2", $caseSensitive: false } })
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, You have to escape '-' by \

```
Message.find({ "$text": { $search: "*\-2*", $caseSensitive: false } })
```

Comment: Your solution also returns sentences contains 2. I solved it with exact matching like "-2". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with exact matching like "-2".